# возможно ли изменить время по умолчанию в php?

Tags: php, datetime, unixtimestamp

Есть огромное количество кода которое использует new DateTime().

Цель: имитировать разное текущее время, например, при получении специального заголовка с датой (смена временных зон не подойдёт).

Можно ли сделать для этой функции свой аргумент по умолчанию?

пока искал информацию нашёл  способ с Runkit , но хотелось бы узнать можно ли сделать это на "чистом" php, без всяких модулей. Либо как можно с минимальными усилиями достичь нужного функционала?

Comment: унаследовать свой класс, например.

Comment: интересный вариант, но проект на symfony, и такой класс все равно надо подключать во всех классах/контроллерах/сервисах, + это не затронет какие-либо библиотеки из vendor